# Do google, yahoo, ebay, amazon..etc.. use any (known: also proprietary/local) web framework?

Tags: frameworks, web

It started as a curiosity but it might get the risk to get philosophical.

So please, stick strictly to the question, and answer for the curiosity part.

I am not sure myself about the definition. So I would use:

[Web Application Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework)

Comment: I'm sure Google uses dozens of frameworks to do things.

Comment: Would you be more specific. I get your point but "dozens" is a bit too generic. I agree they might optimize a lot, but still the question: what they do optimize?

Comment: @Adel GWT seems to be a public tool, it doesn't mean it is used for the google web site. I would expect it to be a derived tool, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google, of course, has frameworks. [One is GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/)

Yahoo has a lot of stuff, including [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)

Comment: For the time being, This is the best answer. I would have liked a bit more arguments. But I started to get into these links a bit more too.